# How do i keep the path in Uri decoded?

Tags: c#, uri, decode, uribuilder

I am trying to create a uri, but for some reason is the path being decoded everytime, causing problems with my browser trying to access the page the uri build?

POC:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var newLocation = new UriBuilder()
        {
            Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
            Host = "localhost",
            Path = "/WebResource.axd?d=0"
        }.Uri;
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello World {newLocation}");
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Hello World
Hello World https://localhost/WebResource.axd%3Fd=0
```

I would have expected:

```
Hello World
Hello World https://localhost/WebResource.axd?d=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is converting the question mark because you specified the question mark in the `.path` instead of in the `.query`. Try moving the `?d=0` into the `.query` and see if you get the same results.

Or, try loading the full URL into the `UriBuilder` using this overload like in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.query?view=net-7.0#system-uribuilder-query): `UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder("http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx?Param1=7890");`

Answer (score 0):

I’m no expert, but it looks like it’s trying to replace the question mark, with it’s ASCII code, or 3F(%3F). This is probably because the question mark means a query in the browser, and is not considered part of the URI. Just a guess, I don’t know how I would fix it.

Hope I could help!